# Testing internal HTTP Request

Tags: laravel, phpunit

**Hello Laravel Developers**,

Today i'm facing some seriously but not at all issue related to testing in Laravel Framework.

See the following code example:

```php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\Api\TokenRequest;
use App\Repositories\ExceptionRepository;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;

class TokenController extends Controller {

    public function __invoke(TokenRequest $request) : JsonResponse
    {
        $http = new Client;

        try {
            $response = $http->post(env('OAUTH_DOMAIN', 'https://oauth.application.com') . '/oauth/token', [
                'form_params' => [
                    'grant_type' => 'password',
                    'client_id' => env('PASSPORT_PASSWORD_CLIENT_ID'),
                    'client_secret' => env('PASSPORT_PASSWORD_CLIENT_SECRET'),
                    'username' => $request->input('email'),
                    'password' => $request->input('password'),
                    'scope' => '*',
                ],
            ]);
            $token = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Token retrieved successfully.',
                'token' => $token,
            ]);
        } catch (Throwable $throwable) {
            ExceptionRepository::emergency('Something went wrong.', $throwable);
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Token can\' be retrieved.',
                'error' => 'Internal server error'
            ], 500);
        }
    }
}
```

This code seems fine but when you're testing you always get internal server error. The TestCase is the following:

```php
<?php

use App\Models\User;

public function test_token()
{
    $user = User::factory()->create()->first();
    $response = $this->json('POST', '/api/token', [
        'email' => $user->email,
        'password' => 'password',
    ]);
    $response->assertStatus(500);
}
```

My ideas about why this happens is because the enviroment variable `OAUTH_DOMAIN` is different of the right application URL when the code is running via PHPUnit.

In other hand when i try this controller i just need start two instances of `artisan serve` because when the framework do a internal request it keep frozen and stuck for infinite time. The `OAUTH_DOMAIN` variable is always the second port of the artisan instance.

Someone know how to face this issue?

Comment: The first thing I see is that you are using `ENV` in a controller, you cannot use that in production as `ENV` is going to be empty, so you have to use `config`. You have to store that in a config file. Also, what is the exception? If you don't know you can use `$this->withoutHandlingException();` inside your test, and it will show the real exception. Also, you don't have to have 2 intances running, you have to [mock](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#testing) the data. Share more information about what you expect to happen, what is happening and anything else that is relevant.